# Signing assemblies in VS2005 BizTalk project

Tags: visual-studio-2005, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

The usual project properties page is not shown when I view properties for a BizTalk 2006R2 project in Visual Studio 2005. Instead I get the property dialog below. How do I get the one where you can choose to sign the assembly, the one with the tabs on the right side?

[image: Project properties]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't manage to fix the actual problem but signed the assembly by manually generating a kay with `sn -k` and assigning it to the assembly in the dialog above.